# Using upvar when procedures are invoked by channel events and retrieving the value to which a pointer points?

Tags: tcl

I have two questions about the following code.

1. Is it possible to use `upvar` in `ReadLine` when it is invoked by the channel event? In experimenting with `upvar`, I used this exact same scenario except `ReadLine` was invoked directly rather than through the event; and it worked fine.  It fails as is because `state($sock)` is not recognized. Is a different `#n` value needed or does it have to be global? It tried `#2` and that threw an error that is was a bad value.
2. In procedure `ReadLine` I tried to make a pointer to `$state($sock)` such that it points to the list itself. In experimenting, it worked fine for `lappend $sptr $op`, for example; but failed on `set row [lindex $sptr 0]` because `$sptr` is `state(1)`. However, it does work if use `set`, such as `set row [lindex [set $sptr] 0]`. Why is this? Is there another method of getting the value to which a pointer is pointing? Is attempting to use pointers in Tcl a bad idea?  Does the fact that the body of procedures are transformed into bytecode representation mean using pointers doesn't make much difference?

Thank you.

```
proc ClientConnect {sock client_ip client_port} {    
   if {![info exists state($sock)]} {set state($sock) {1}}; 
   chan configure $sock -buffering line -blocking 0 -translation crlf
   chan event $sock readable [list ReadLine $sock]
}

proc ReadLine {sock} {

  # The #1 in upvar is to first caller, which is ClientConnect.
  # Make a ptr to the array list rather than retrieving it each reference,
  # such that $sptr is state($sock)'s list.

  upvar #1 state r
  set sptr r($sock)
  puts stdout "x: [lindex $r($sock) 0]"; #Fails to recognize state.
  set row [lindex [set $sptr] 0]
}
```

The experimenting code that appears to work properly:

```
proc ReadLine {sock} {
 upvar #1 row rtemp; #Recognizes row.
 set r rtemp($sock)
 lappend $r "new"

 set line "Content-length: 247899"
 if { [string first "Content-length:" $line] == 0 } { lappend $r [string trim [string range $line 16 end]] }

 lappend $r "help"
 puts [lindex [set $r] 3]; #Output is: 247899.
 puts $rtemp($sock); #Output is: 1 GET new 247899 help.
}
    
proc do {sock} {
  set row($sock) {1 GET}
  ReadLine $sock
}

set sock 1
do $sock
```

Comment: IIRC, a channel event handler doesn't have a call stack (or rather it's the first level in a new one) so `upvar` with anything but `#0` seems unlikely to be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `upvar` if you want, but you'll find that the only stack frame visible above the callback is the global stack frame. It's as if it was invoked with `uplevel #0`. It can't see inside procedures, and if you think a bit about it the reason is obvious: there's no guarantee that any particular procedure would be on the stack when the call happens.

If you're needing to pass state from the place where you install the callback to where it is invoked, the easiest ways involve either using a coroutine (which can be resumed from the actual global callback) or using a TclOO object (which can encapsulate all sorts of complex state, of course). In 8.5 and before, you're more restricted and have to use global/namespace variables, which can get messier.

---

To make your variable access work, use `upvar` to make an alias to the variable:

```
# upvar 0 is special in that it aliases a currently-visible variable
upvar 0 row($sock) r
puts [lindex $r 0]
```

The only real restriction is that you can't put arrays inside arrays. That got removed ages ago because it was hard to use and inclined to cause crashes.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  I didn't understand that `#0` could be used without using `global`.  As I work more using many smaller procedures, it seems difficult to use `upvar` as a means of modifying the same variable. For example, if use it to reference `state` in `ReadLine` and want to call `CloseSock` from there, which performs `unset state($sock)`, it appears `upvar` can't be used again to reference `state`. A global variable appears simpler but I've read that global variables should not be used. or used minimally. Is that true?